# Mongoose - query documents with find() where sum of nested array values is in certain range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have documents of a collection that look like following:

```
{
   items: [
      {
          price: 80
      },
      {
          price: 70
      }
   ]
},
{
   items: [
      {
          price: 100
      },
      {
          price: 85
      }
   ]
},
{
   items: [
      {
          price: 200
      },
      {
          price: 85
      }
   ]
},
...
```

I want to be able to query all documents with `MyObj.find(query)` where the sum of all item prices is between a given range. For example, $gte 160 and $lte 200 which would only return me the document the second document in the example.

```
const query = ???
const filteredDocs = await MyObj.find(query).exec()
```

How would the query for this look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can use aggregation. First, add field represent the sum of items price with [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) and [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) then find document has that field match your conditions. Something like:

```
MyObj.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      total: {
        $sum: "$items.price"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      total: {
        $gte: 160,
        $lte: 200
      }
    }
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_6hVS7AzWLv)

**EDIT:** If you only want to use `find()`, you can try [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/):

```
MyObj.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $gte: [
          {
            $sum: "$items.price"
          },
          160
        ]
      },
      {
        $lte: [
          {
            $sum: "$items.price"
          },
          200
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1PBN46fOS89)

Comment: is this also somehow possible to do with just a find() instead of an aggreate()? I'm restricted in the way that I have to use the former.